# How to split value using comma from the my database table's particular column?

Tags: java, mysql

I have one table called `Product` which contains column named `PriceWithDescription`.

This above mentioned table's column contains data like as below.

```
1>  pricevalue : One,and more ,pricevalue : two
```

I want to split the values so that I can get the result as below.

```
1> pricevalue : One,and more
2> pricevalue : two
```

When I split data using "," it give me result like below.

```
1> pricevalue : One
2> and more
3> pricevalue : two
```

So, what is the best way to split value when value itself contains comma as value.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Your DB is not in 1st Normal form. So, in java maybe you can split on `pricevalue` and get it's values and attach `pricevalue` manually while displaying. You can also opt for a regex. But, better make it in 1 NF to avoid such operations.

Comment: In java also, I have to use split() function which will give the same result.Can you please give me RegX solution?

Comment: try this String[] priceSplit = test.split("pricevalue :");

Comment: Put a whitespace before the comma: `"pricevalue : One,and more ,pricevalue : two".split(" ,");

Answer (score 3):

Consider redesigning your table structure to make it more fit to store key-value pairs.

But you can use a positive lookahead: splitting is only needed if there is another `:` coming up, and there cannot be any `,` before then. This leads to something like:

```
,(?=[^,]*?:)
```

Java code:

```
String s = "pricevalue : One,and more ,pricevalue : two,something else : abc , def";

String[] ss = s.split(",(?=[^,]*?:)");
for(String si : ss) {
    System.out.println(si);
}
```

https://ideone.com/v66rTO

Output:

```
pricevalue : One,and more 
pricevalue : two
something else : abc , def
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `String#split` using a regex with a lookahead for `pricevalue`

[The regex](https://regex101.com/r/G254to/1) : `,(?=pricevalue)`

[Example in Java](https://ideone.com/8m1S3F)

```
String str = "pricevalue : One,and more ,pricevalue : two";
String[] splitted = str.split(",(?=pricevalue)");
for (String s : splitted) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Prints

```
pricevalue : One,and more 
pricevalue : two
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But, here pricevalue can be anything so i can not split using above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do.

1) Use this code `'something.split("pricevalue :")'`

This returns three elements.

2) Ignore the first element.

3) For all elements that are not the last element , remove the comma at the end of the string.

You will get this.

```
1> pricevalue : One,and more
2> pricevalue : two
```